# InteliJ Idea android application jakarta-commons-collections Multiple dex files define

Tags: java, android, json

Well I'm trying to add json library in my android Java app:

```
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
    public void sendMessage(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(TestActivity.this, RegActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        String loginPasswordJSON=this.generateJson(this.login.getText().toString(),this.password.getText().toString()) ;
        System.out.println(loginPasswordJSON);
    }

    private String generateJson(String login, String password){
        JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
        j.put("login",login);
        j.put("password",password);
        String res=j.toString();
        return res;
    }
```

I've recieved some class not found exeption. In some answers and in [official site](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/).
I found decision to install that jars:

```
jakarta commons-lang 2.5
jakarta commons-beanutils 1.8.0
jakarta commons-collections 3.2.1
jakarta commons-logging 1.1.1
ezmorph 1.0.6
```

When I install

```
jakarta commons-logging 1.1.1
jakarta commons-beanutils 1.8.0
ezmorph 1.0.6
```

The mistake remains, but when I install:

```
   jakarta commons-collections 3.2.1
    jakarta commons-lang 2.5
```

There is folowing mistake:

```
Error:Android Dex: [test] Unable to execute DX
Error:Android Dex: [test] com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap;
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you should check if that class is included more times in your build path: Ctrl+N, check the box about searching in library and type the class name, you should only find one result.

If it still doesn't work, try rebuild the project, it will clear old caches.

Answer (score 0):

There is a 'org/apache/commons/collections' package in the beanUtils jar file, while a package with the same name in collections jar file, which cause the 'Multiple dex files define' problem.

Use beanUtils v1.9.2 should solve your problem.